# How can I find all the variables 2D or higher in a netcdf file using python?

Tags: python, netcdf

I would like to find all the variables in a netcdf file that have two or more dimensions.  In other words, get a list of all the variables that are *not* 0 or 1 dimensional.

It seems I should be able to do something like:

`import netCDF4
nc = netCDF4.Dataset(file)
varlist = [<something> k,v in nc.variables.iteritems()]`

where  uses `v.ndim > 1` but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there with the list comprehension you provided.  The boolean condition goes at the end though, not at the beginning.

```
[(nm, var) for nm, var in nc.variables.iteritems() if var.ndim > 1]
```

That outputs a list of length-2 tuples, each one containing the name and the netCDF4 variable object.  If you just want the variables, you can do

```
[var for var in nc.variables.itervalues() if var.ndim > 1]
```

List comprehensions are a really powerful tool; see the official documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions